# Listening to events when using Moralis provider

Tags: events, moralis

I would like to listen to an event emitted by a function of my smartcontract with javascript.

```
filter = {
address: THE_ADDRESS_OF_YOUR_CONTRACT,
topics: [
    // the name of the event, parnetheses containing the data type of each event, no spaces
    utils.id("WinnerPicked(address)")
]}
provider.on(filter, (address) => {
   console.log(address)
})
```

However, I'm also using Moralis, and I don't know how to get the "provider" to do "provider.on". I can't find a function "getMoralisProvider" or something like this.
This listening of event is used in a component in react, and the father of this component is wrapped with `<MoralisProvider initializeOnMount={false}>`

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a web3 provider you can do for example:

```
const { enableWeb3 } = useMoralis(); 

const provider = await enableWeb3(); // provider from injected wallet e.g. MetaMask extension

provider.on('block', (blockNumber) => {
   console.log('blockNumber', blockNumber);
});
```

Reference: https://v1docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/web3/web3#connectors

If you have a backend, you may also be interested in using the [Streams API](https://docs.moralis.io/docs/streams-api) where event data is streamed to your backend in real-time.